# How to modify a numeric JSON field using an Argonaut lens?

Tags: json, scala, lenses, argonaut

Here's a simplified version of an example on [Argonaut's lens documentation](http://argonaut.io/doc/zipper/):

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._

val obj: Json = Parse.parseOption("""{"a":{"b":"x","c":2}}""").get

val lens1 = jObjectPL >=> jsonObjectPL("a") >=>
            jObjectPL >=> jsonObjectPL("b") >=> jStringPL

lens1.mod(_ + "y", obj)
// res0: argonaut.Json = {"a":{"b":"xy","c":2}}
```

How do you do a similar thing with numeric fields? For example, suppose we wanted to add `1` to the number in `obj` above, to get a result of

```
// res1: argonaut.Json = {"a":{"b":"x","c":3}}
```

My first attempt is to try

```
val lens2 = jObjectPL >=> jsonObjectPL("a") >=>
            jObjectPL >=> jsonObjectPL("c") >=> jNumberPL

lens2.mod(_ + 1, obj)
```

But this last line doesn't compile.

Comment: Side note: "PL" stands for "partial lens", as these are Scalaz [PLens](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.PLensFamily) instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsonString` in Argonaut is simply a type alias for `String`, but numbers are slightly more complicated because there is no core Scala type that can perfectly represent numbers in JSON.

The numeric type in Argonaut is `JsonNumber`, so the type of the first argument passed to `mod` needs to be `(JsonNumber) => JsonNumber`.

The `JsonNumber` subtypes with public constructors are:

- `JsonLong`
- `JsonBigDecimal`
- `JsonDouble`

Here's a corrected version of the last line of code in the question, using `JsonBigDecimal`:

```
lens2.mod(i => JsonBigDecimal(i.toBigDecimal + 1), obj)
```